# How to apply multiple methods from a list with class objects over Pandas DataFrame in Parallel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I have a list of "classifiers" and each have a "predict" method. So for example, take the following code

```
import pandas as pd

class ClassifierA():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
    def predict(self, x):
        return x + 5
    
class ClassifierB(): 
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
    def predict(self, x):
        return x + 10
    
class ClassifierC():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
    def predict(self, x):
        return x - 10

classifierA = ClassifierA(name="classifierA")
classifierB = ClassifierB(name="classifierB")
classifierC = ClassifierC(name="classifierC")

list_of_classifiers = [classifierA, classifierB, classifierC]
```

In this case, the classifiers do something very simple, but in the real world, imagine they actually perform some prediction.

Now, imagine we have a Pandas DataFrame with many observations. In this case, 10 observations each is just a number from 1 to 10.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
})
```

How can I apply each of the classifiers in the list to `df.x` in parallel? The output of what I want to achieve is the same as:

```
for classifier in list_of_classifiers:
    df['{}_prediction'.format(classifier.name)] = df['x'].apply(lambda x: classifier.predict(x))
```

which yields

```
    x   classifierA_prediction  classifierB_prediction  classifierC_prediction
0   1   6   11  -9
1   2   7   12  -8
2   3   8   13  -7
3   4   9   14  -6
4   5   10  15  -5
5   6   11  16  -4
6   7   12  17  -3
7   8   13  18  -2
8   9   14  19  -1
9   10  15  20  0
```

but the problem here is that I'm looping over each classifier in the list and also looping over each row in the dataframe via `apply`. I wonder if there's something more efficient.

For example, I could also do

```
predictions = df['x'].apply(
    lambda x: (classifierA.predict(x), classifierB.predict(x), classifierC.predict(x)))
```

but the problem there is that then I am specifying each classifier manually and the list might be very big.

Comment: I can't think of a way that avoids looping through the classifiers, but you could maybe use `multiprocessing` for running the classifiers in parallel?

Comment: You can use `joblib` to do that with `Parallel` and `delayed`.

Comment: This comprehensive article on that topic might be useful: https://www.wrighters.io/options-to-run-pandas-dataframe-apply-in-parallel/